# Angular UI pager directive does not re-render when label text changes

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularJS with Angular UI Bootstrap. For i18n I am using angular-translate which provides a filter `| translate` to handle the translation. Using the following code, the `previous-text` and `next-text` of the `pager` directive are not updated in view, whereas all other labels change correctly when changing the language.

How can I force the pager directive to re-render corresponding to the current translation? Should I address this as bug/new feature at angular-ui or angular-translate?

Same behavior occurs with other components (e.g. Alert).

```
<div ng-controller="LanguageCtrl">
    <a href="#{{$location.path()}}" ng-click="switchLang('de_CH')">DE</a>
    <a href="#{{$location.path()}}" ng-click="switchLang('fr_CH')">FR</a>
</div>

<pager total-items="size" items-per-page="10" page="page" 
    previous-text="{{'PREV' | translate}}" 
    next-text="{{'NEXT' | translate}}"/>
```

And here the controller for switching the language:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('LanguageCtrl', ['$translate', '$scope',
    function ($translate, $scope) {
        $scope.switchLang = function (lang) {
            $translate.uses(lang);
        };
    }]);
```

**Update 1**

Note: When I reload the page, the labels are correctly displayed in the desired language! But I want to implement it without reloading.

Comment: The reason could as simple as unavailability of the translation for `PREV` and `NEXT`. Please verify translation exists.

Comment: thanks, yes it exists. when i completely reload the page, one can see the correct translation.

Comment: created issue at angular-translate [https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-translate/issues/301](https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-translate/issues/301)

Comment: Can you add a test case, plunkr or jsfiddle maybe? I would suggest the component itself is not be notified about a language change.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! Since you're using the filter, the next $digest cycle should actually pick things up. And obviously it does, otherwise the language would not have changed after a page reload.

I think we have to look under the hood of angular-ui pager here. Maybe the pager directive caches given labels?

Comment: it is close but in real, the `-text` attributes are working like a string constants, directive re render refresh this values with actual data

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I re read [Pagination doc](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and it seems that a `-text` atrributes marked as `C`. From the docs

> this setting can be configured globally in a constant service

The `-text` attributes looks like a constants. Outside the page directive I print out `{{ 'PREV' | translate }}`, it it working as expected and hangs in the pagination directive. I think it will be a good choice to force reload states on the page what are sensitive about the locale. I do this way but you can rewrite my code, use main idea

decorator

```
$provide.decorator('$state', function($delegate, $stateParams) {
        $delegate.forceReload = function() {
            return $delegate.go($delegate.current, $stateParams, {
                reload: true,
                inherit: false,
                notify: true
            });
        };
        return $delegate;
    });
```

using

```
$rootScope.$on(APP_EVENTS.LOCALE_CHANGED, function (event, data) {
    $state.forceReload();
});
```

**UPDATED**

I discovered that there is a cheat to re render just a pagination directive without refresh a whole page. Its sensitive with the `total-items` attribute.

```
var total = $scope.totalItems;
$scope.totalItems = 0
$scope.totalItems = total;
```

The directive re rendered and all `-text` attributes re rendered also with the new localized strings.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested it, but the following seems like it would work:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('LanguageCtrl', ['$translate', '$scope',
    function ($translate, $scope) {
        $scope.switchLang = function (lang) {
            $translate.uses(lang);
        };
        $scope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function () {
            // this will be called after switching languages,
            // so you could force a $scope.PREV here and
            // change your HTML to use a variable.
            // However, maybe just calling $translate will
            // force your frontend to update
            $translate('PREV');
            $translate('NEXT');
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: problem is not in the translation calls, see my answer

Answer (score -3):

I has a similar problem with updating values and found that using 'apply()' worked. Maybe try this;

```
function ($translate, $scope) {
$scope.switchLang = function (lang) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $translate.uses(lang);
    });
};}]);
```

Comment: thanks, but this does not work, since it is invoked via ng-click. Results in an error: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress`

Comment: If an apply should be invoked explicitly, this could be helpful: `$timeout(function(){}, 1)` (`$timeout` invokes implicitly an `$apply` However, mostly that's only dirty hacking without solving the original issue. ;)